# Multiselect editor on kendo grid

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

I was trying to bind a collection property into kendo grid.

I have this models

```
class Student {
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
   public string CourseDescriptions {
     get {
       return Courses.Select(x => x.Description).Join(", ");
     }
   }
}

class Course {
   public int CourseId { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'am trying to bound Courses and create a multiselect dropdown.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Student>()
 .Name("student-grid")
 .Columns(columns =>
 {
     columns.Bound(x => x.StudentId).Title("StudentId");
     columns.Bound(x => x.Courses)
         .ClientTemplate("#=CourseDescriptions#");
 })
 .ToolBar(toolbar =>
 {
     toolbar.Create().Text(R.Generic.AddNewRecord);
 })
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
```

[Student Courses Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc8TI.png)
The idea is to show the courses comma separated when on view mode. But change it into multi select dropdown with preselected values on edit mode.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom editor template for the `Courses` column, create a "CoursesEditor.cshtml" file in EditorTemplates with the following content.

```
﻿@model IEnumerable<Course>

@(
    Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
        .DataTextField("Description")
        .DataValueField("CourseId")
        .BindTo((IEnumerable<Course>)ViewData["courses"])
)
```

Specify the editor name in the model definition:

```
class Student {
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   
   [UIHint("CoursesEditor")]
   public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
   public string CourseDescriptions {
     get {
       return Courses.Select(x => x.Description).Join(", ");
     }
   }
}
```

Don't forget to seed the `ViewData` with the multiselect data in your controller:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private DataRepository repository = new DataRepository();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["courses"] = repository.Courses;

            return View();
        }
```

There is a runnable example in this repo:

- https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/multiselect-in-grid